# Scripting vim's file has changed externally detection

Tags: vim

When you change a file outside vim, vim notices, and prompts you for action: should it reload the file, and discard any changes you have? should it keep your changes?

Often, just re-reading the buffer is correct. Typically, this occurs:

- Open a file in vim.
- Hack away, save.
- Change branches in git.
- Vim detects the file has changed.

At this point, I really just want the file to get reloaded, as it is saved. (If the buffer isn't saved, the normal prompt is okay.) Me clicking/typing "Load file" is error prone if I have a stray buffer that *isn't* saved. Seeing that message only for buffers that are modified would be much safer.

Something that does exactly what I want would be great, but I've really got other desires too (diffing a modified buffer would be cool): can you script what happens when a file changes on-disk?

Answer (score 1):

If `:set autoread` is not enough, you can indeed script the behavior; on this occasion, the `FileChangedShell` event is fired, and you can hook into that and influence the behavior. See `:help FileChangedShell` for details.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like vim's autoread option would do what you're looking for.  You can turn that on by adding the following to your `vimrc` file or typing it into a vim session:

```
:set autoread
```

You can get more information about the option by using:

```
:help 'autoread'
```

For information on viewing the differences between what's in the vim buffer and what's on disk run:

```
:help :DiffOrig
```

That contains some code that you can put into your `vimrc` file, to define a `:DiffOrig` command that will do exactly that.